Why is the displacement -time graph of an object thrown upwards a downward parabola?

So, this is the displacement-time graph of an object thrown upwards with an initial velocity $u$. I  understand the first part as the equation is $s = -ut + \frac{at^2}{2}$ which is simply the equation of a parabola of the form $X = 4Y^2$ but after the object reaches the maximum height the equation changes to $s = -ut - \frac{at^2}{2}$ and this should result in the parabola to be discontinuous and in the 4th quadrant but the graph is continuous and in the first quadrant.
Why is this so?

The continuous trajectory is described by a single function $s(t)$, it does not change at any point during the motion. Maybe you need to verify that you are using the correct function $s(t)$ to describe your motion to accommodate this fact. Also, don't confuse the trajectory $s(t)$ in time with the trajectory in space, eg. $s(x)$.

Can you please elaborate on what is the difference between the two functions

It is just a different function. For your case, $s(x)$ would be just a line on $x=0$ since you launch your mass straight up. Hence, the motion has no $x$-component and the traveled distance $s$ is independent of $x$. However, if you would launch your mass at an angle, you would also obtain a parabola for $s(x)$ and sometimes, people confuse $s(t)$ and $s(x)$. However, below, there is an answer along the same lines that I gave: the trajectory is smooth and so is your function $s(t)$, you just need to check your sign convention.

I feel like it should be
$$
s(t) = ut - \frac{at^2}{2}
$$
That aside, note the behaviour of $t$ and $t^2$ as $t$ increases from the initial value $t=0$: For $t\in(0,1)$, you always have $t^2<t$, whereas for $t>1$, you always have $t^2>t$, with equality at $t=1$. This means that initially, the term which is linear in $t$ dominates the behaviour of your trajectory, until you hit the critical point (which in your case would be $\frac{u}{g}$) and the quadratic behaviour takes over. In other words, in the beginning, the term $ut$ grows faster than the term $\frac{at^2}{2}$. However, after $\frac{u}{g}$ units of time have passed, the term $\frac{at^2}{2}$ will grow faster than the $ut$ term, leading to the trajectory going downwards again precisely due to the sign difference between these terms. If the formula would indeed change as you propose, the second half of the curve would be flipped upside down, and the particle would accelerate upwards, which is of course not what we want.
A mathematical afterthought: You mention that if the formula were to change in the way you propose, the curve would be discontinuous at the point $t = \frac{at^2}{2}$. This is not true; one can easily "patch together" functions like this and get a result that is continuous. Consider the function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}g(x): x < x_0\\ h(x): x\geq x_0\end{cases}
$$
The only thing that matters now for the continuity of $f$ is that $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ tend towards the same limit as $x\rightarrow x_0$. One can extend this to the derivatives of $f$ by simply imposing the same condition on the derivatives of $g$ and $h$.

You got the signs wrong, the equation to use is $s=ut-\frac{gt^2}{2}$, and this is valid throughout the entire trajectory. You can see then why the graph is represented by a parabola.

by symmetry, it does not really matter which sign is used. Using OPs convention would produce an upside down version of the posted image, with the maximum height in the negative - this seems weird, but aside from the negative sign, yields exactly the same physics.
